# X values out of bound in Axes3D

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I'm plotting a 3D chart which looks like this
[image: 3D plot]

When I try to limit the axis, the values go out of bounds
[image: 2nd #D plot]

What am I doing wrong?

the code:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.set_xlim3d(0,1000)
#ax.set_ylim3d(0,1000)
#ax.set_zlim3d(0,5000)
Y = 'allocated_time_on_page'
X = 'allocated_actions'
Z = 'avg_days_between_visits'

y = df_try[Y]
x = df_try[X]
z = df_try[Z]

ax.set_xlabel(X)
ax.set_ylabel(Y)
ax.set_zlabel(Z)

g = ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='o',depthshade=True,c=df_try['logo_renewal'],alpha=.4)
#g = ax.scatter(x, y, z, marker='o',depthshade=True,c=df_try['proba'],cmap='RdYlGn',alpha=.4)
legend = ax.legend(*g.legend_elements(), loc="lower center", title="X Values", borderaxespad=-10, ncol=4)
ax.add_artist(legend)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I though that setting `clip_on` equal to `True` would fix this, but it doesn't. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: You set `ax.set_xlim3d()` less than the range of your data.

Comment: of course but if I set the data to be less, the range would adjust itself automatically. So what's the point of the set_xlim3d()?...